# How to change the memory allocator for libxml API?

Tags: memory, libxml2

When using libxml API, the lib will automatically allocate some memory.

How can I change the default memory allocator/deallocator for libxml?

Is there any API for this purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's an API. Have a look at the functions provided by the [*xmlmemory* module](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlmemory.html), especially [`xmlMemSetup`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlmemory.html#xmlMemSetup):

```c
int xmlMemSetup (xmlFreeFunc freeFunc, 
                 xmlMallocFunc mallocFunc, 
                 xmlReallocFunc reallocFunc, 
                 xmlStrdupFunc strdupFunc)
```

> Override the default memory access functions with a new set. This has to be called before any other libxml routines!